# If Having More Than x Then Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there anyway to have HAVING and WHERE clauses work in conjecture with each other?  ie psuedocode:

```
CASE
   HAVING count(children) > 3 THEN WHERE nationality = 'Mexican'
   HAVING count(children) = 2 THEN WHERE nationality = 'American'
   HAVING count(children) = 1 THEN WHERE nationality = 'Japanese'
END
```

Comment: You can't do that - maybe subquery and use multiple conditions in your WHERE instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your query inside of another `SELECT`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT count(children) as ChildrenCount, nationality 
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY nationality 
) x
WHERE 
    (ChildrenCount > 3 AND nationality = 'Mexican')
    OR
    (ChildrenCount = 2 AND nationality = 'American')
    OR
    (ChildrenCount = 1 AND nationality = 'Japanese')
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the logic that you want?

Let me guess that you want Mexicans with more than 3 children, Americans with 2, and Japanese with 1.  In this case, you would something like:

```
having (case when count(nationality = 'Mexican' then children end) > 3 then 'true'
             when count(nationality = 'American' then children end) = 2 then 'true'
             when count(nationality = 'Japanese' then children end) = 1 then 'true'
        end) = 'true'
```

However, even this seems strange.  Why are you counting "children".  What are you grouping on?  If children is just a field in the data, then this should be a WHERE clause instead of a HAVING clause:

```
where (nationality = 'Mexican' and children end > 3) or
      (nationality = 'American' and children = 2) or
      (nationality = 'Japanese' and children = 1)
```

Comment: Need to know what column is `children` being grouped on or the guess here is correct +1

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your existing query in a CTE to separate the counting and grouping from the filtering, and then use the count from the CTE in your final WHERE clause with a CASE:

```
;WITH [Counts] AS
(
    SELECT
        ,nationality
        ,COUNT(children) AS [children]
    FROM
        xyz
    GROUP BY
        nationality
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Counts]
WHERE 
    nationality = 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN [children] > 3 THEN 'Mexican'
            WHEN [children] = 2 THEN 'American'
            WHEN [children] = 1 THEN 'Japanese' 
        END
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS SHOULD WORK

```
DECLARE @table TABLE     
(    
     nationality varchar (25),  
     totalchildren int
)   

insert @table  
    SELECT nationality,COUNT(children) AS totalchildren 
    FROM TABLENAME
    GROUP BY nationality

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @table  
WHERE 
    nationality = 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN totalchildren > 3 THEN 'Mexican'
            WHEN totalchildren = 2 THEN 'American'
            WHEN totalchildren = 1 THEN 'Japanese' 
        END
    )
```